# Positioning of an arrow in an HTML select

Tags: html, css

I'm using a custom arrow in my selects. They have different widths and I cannot figure out how to position them so that the distance from the right edge of the select to the arrow is exactly the same in all of them.

Currently I use `background position 95%` what looks ok-ish but not ideal.

```css
select{
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat 95%;
 -moz-appearance: none; 
 -webkit-appearance: none; 
 appearance: none;
        padding : 4px 20px
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes Super Long Option</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Position from the right and use a non dynamic unit of measurement to position the arrows just how far you want from the right (I used px):

```
select{
        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat;
        background-position: right 5px top; /* Change the px value here to change the distance */
        -moz-appearance: none; 
        -webkit-appearance: none; 
        appearance: none;
            padding : 4px 20px
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I added `background-position:right;` and deleted your `95%`

```css
select{
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat;
  background-position:right;
 -moz-appearance: none; 
 -webkit-appearance: none; 
 appearance: none;
        padding : 4px 20px
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes Super Long Option</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
/* FIX OF UGLY SELECT */
SELECT {
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg height='10px' width='10px' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000000' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7.247 11.14 2.451 5.658C1.885 5.013 2.345 4 3.204 4h9.592a1 1 0 0 1 .753 1.659l-4.796 5.48a1 1 0 0 1-1.506 0z'/></svg>") no-repeat;
    background-position: calc(100% - 0.75rem) center !important;
    -moz-appearance:none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important; 
    appearance: none !important;
    padding-right: 2rem !important;
}
```

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Opera:

[image]

Edge:

[image]

p.s. Design Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 3):

```css
select{
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat;
 -moz-appearance: none; 
 -webkit-appearance: none; 
 appearance: none;
        padding : 4px 20px;
        background-position:100%;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes Super Long Option</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

using `background-position:100%;` will allow you to put the background always on the end of the select

Answer (score 3):

You can use `background-position` and `background-size` property

```css
select{
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat 95%;
 -moz-appearance: none; 
 -webkit-appearance: none; 
    background-size: 20px 35px;
    background-position: 100%;
 appearance: none;
        padding : 4px 20px
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes Super Long Option</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-position:right` and the image will be there on right with equal position from right.

```css
select{
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat;
 -moz-appearance: none; 
 -webkit-appearance: none; 
 appearance: none;
 background-position: top right;
        padding : 4px 20px
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes Super Long Option</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**Another Concern**

You might be required some space from right but equal space so suggest you to cut the image with some space so that you will see the image with some gap and position will be equal.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put a litteral value instead of 95% for example 5px , because the two select are not identical so 95% is not the same for the both

```css
select{
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat right 5px;
 -moz-appearance: none; 
 -webkit-appearance: none; 
 appearance: none;
        padding : 4px 20px
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes Super Long Option</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer this question exactly, but figured I would throw it in here in case someone was looking to move the existing icon off the right edge a bit. I found you can do this by using outline instead of border (if you need a border) and then add a transparent border in order to give some padding between the outline and the dropdown caret.

```css
select {
    color: black;
    outline: solid 1px black;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

select.padding {
    border: 0px solid black;
    border-right-width: 10px;
    border-color: transparent;
    outline: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Test</option>
</select>

<select class="padding">
  <option>Test</option>
</select>
```